# How should I recycle a node from a tree?

Tags: java, memory-management

[EDIT]Problem solved, I found the leak. Thank you very much.

I'm running a scheduling algorithm, with nodes that stores the following data:

```
int job[] = new int[Algo.NUM_MACHINES];
int remTime[] = new int[Algo.NUM_MACHINES];
int res = Algo.RESOURCE;
int time = 0;
int tardy = 0;

//Job jobTree[] = new Job[Algo.NUM_JOBS];
ArrayList<Integer> jobsFinished = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int id;
boolean visited = false;
Machine parent = this;//so that root node points to himself
ArrayList<Machine> children = new ArrayList<Machine>();

int duplicate = 0;//duplicate (sj-sj-sj-sj-...) flag
```

Each node has an ArrayList that leads to its children, and a parent node that leads to its parent.

When I determine a node is no longer needed, is

```
node.parent.children.remove(node);
node.parent=null;
```

enough to cause the node be recycled? How would you write the code to recycle the node?

Comment: What do you think? This is a very, very common question about how the GC works, do you believe your situation is different in some way?

Comment: I think this should be able to remove the reference from the node, but the profiler says differently.

Comment: Either you have removed all the strong references or you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an object recyclable in a garbage-collected environment, you have to ensure that there are no references to it from reachable objects.

Garbage collection sees what objects are reachable by following references.  When you overwrite a reference or set it to `null`, you're burning a bridge to the target object, and if there's no other way to get to that object, the memory can be reclaimed.

As far as I can tell, you don't need this line:

```
node.parent=null;
```

because `node` becomes unreachable when it's removed from the ArrayList (unless there's a pointer to it elsewhere in the application).  If `node` is unreachable, it doesn't matter what it points to because it's already sunk.

If nodes aren't being collected, but you think they should be, try to find out what is pointing to them.  It might even be a parameter or variable up in the stack somewhere keeping the memory pinned.

*Disclaimer: I don't know Java, so I don't know exactly how its VM works.  I'm going by my knowledge of garbage collection in general.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have accurately described the Node data structure and accurately described the "algorithm" for "recycling" a node, then it should work.

If the profiler is telling you that nodes are still reachable when they shouldn't be then one (or more) of the following *must* be true:

- You have live (strong) references to the nodes in local variables, method parameters, or some other data structure separate from the tree.
- Your tree is not actually tree shaped; i.e. the nodes have been linked into the tree in more than one place.
- You are not calling the code to recycle nodes.

Comment: I have a function call that takes a node as a parameter. When the method returns, does the strong reference break as well?

Comment: @Sheldon - it depends on what the function did with the reference.

Comment: So normally, it would break. But if you were to, ie assign it to a field, the reference shall remain, right?